# knockout if syntax

Tags: javascript, if-statement, knockout.js

I have the following code with some knockout syntax:

```
<h2 data-bind="text: $root[$root.primaryKey]() ? 'Edit' : 'Create New'"></h2>
```

Based on the same syntax `$root[$root.primaryKey]()` I want to do a simple if syntax check for another div so I know what to show, an updatable content or to the form to add a new article.

So, how could I do something like

```
if $root[$root.primaryKey]()
  <div> update content </div>
else 
  <div> new content </div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with using the `if` binding?

Comment: Nothing, but it has to be based on something... I don't have that something and don't want to create it... don't know if you understand my point, i will review the question

Comment: You could use the container less bindings. Check the end of the link that you have posted. Note that KO does not have an else, you would need two if conditions, one checking for true and the other checking for false

Comment: @ryadavilli it's what I am trying now

Comment: Actually, it would be better if you explained your question, especially after reading your comment about it being based on some thing and not wanting to create that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use virtual elements:

```
<!-- ko if: $root[$root.primaryKey]() -->
   <div> update content </div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: $root[$root.primaryKey]() -->
   <div> new content </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: What is the return value of $root[$root.primaryKey]() ??? Unless it is a true or false it will not work. you might want to compare to some specific value in your if condition in that case

Comment: I'm trying to find out... as it's not my code, I'm learning knockout working with someone else's code

Comment: `This template engine does not support the 'if' binding within its templates`

Comment: It seems to me that you are you using old version of knockout.js. Could you update it to the latest?

Comment: lol @ArtemVyshniakov It seams I use the latest version, 2.2.0

Comment: Even better, I'm working on Administrator Laravel bundle... admin.js and custom-bindings.js for edit.php in views, trying to implement the image upload feature for when New article only (for now)

Comment: i've done it another way... so I will take your answer for granted as I know this would've worked in another case.